# pop() is not a function - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a strange error with NodeJS when I call the function `pop()` on an array, it says `TypeError: cars.pop is not a function`... I am confused.

Any help? Below is the code. Thank you,

```
//callback chaining to avoid having multiple callbacks in the event queue
//only one callback calling others
function showCar(car, callback) {
  console.log('Saw a ' + car);
  if (car.length) {
    //register the function as asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
      callback();
    })
  }
}

function logCars(cars) {
  var car = cars.pop();
  showCar(car, function() { //chaining of call backs
    logCars(car);
  });
}
var cars = ['ferrari', 'porsh', 'Hyundai', 'Peugeot'];
logCars(cars);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you aren't passing an array to the `logCars` function on the second call. You are passing the popped string on the second recursive call.

In other words, `logCars(car)` should be `logCars(cars)` where you are nesting callbacks:

```
function logCars (cars){
  var car = cars.pop();
  showCar(car, function () {
    logCars(cars); // This should be `cars`, not `car` like you had
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. However, it only returns one call from the list. It should be returning asynchronous calls to the list and display the list.

Comment: Thank you Josh, I just fixed it...I had some typos in the code lol